# How to implement UITextView.hidden

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview

I'm developing an iOS 5 app.
I can't understand why

```
myTextView.hidden = YES;
```

or

```
myTextView.hidden = NO;
```

is not working?

I have also tried to use `[myTextView setHidden:( ! [myTextView isHidden])];`
I have myTextView default set to hidden through IB in the xib.
Any help would be great!
Thanks

Comment: have you forget to connect the IBOutlet ?

Comment: How is myTextView being declared?

Comment: @Ríomhaire are you using Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the connection between the `IBOutlet` and the `UITextView` on the Xib file established? That's my best guess for why that's not working.

**Edit:** I am assuming you have create the `UITextView` on the Xib and not on the code.

Comment: Thank You Very Much. This was indeed the problem.

Comment: If this helped you out, please mark it has correct, so it can help other people.

Answer (score 1):

Just try: `[myTextView setHidden:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

in .h

```
UITextView *myTextView;

@property(nonatomic, assign) UITextView *myTextView;
```

in .m

```
[myTextView setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could make this operation smoother is to have an image identical to your loading image which overlays your entire view. Mark it as

[self.OverlayView setHidden:false];

so that it overlays your start screen. If you then need to display your start screen then simply set

[self.OverlayView setHidden:true];

this will give you a seamless transition to your login screen (a bit of a cludge but works great!)